# Selectize.js update option label from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a drop down select field rendered from server, and it contains the currently selected option only, with value but no text.

```
<select name="countryCode">
  <option value="US" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Later, I initialize it with selectize

```
$('[name=countryCode]').selectize({
  load: function(query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: `countryCode.php?q=${query}`
    }).done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => callback(data.countryCodes));
  }
});
```

where `countryCode.php` returns the following json

```
{
  countryCodes: [{
    text: 'United States',
    value: 'US'
  },
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to update the text label of the previously rendered option?